# Error when compiling Android application: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid class name"

Tags: android

Trying to compile Android application I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid class name (must not contain . ; [ < > or :): io/fotoapparat/Fotoapparat;
```

Gradle plugin: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06

Answer (score 0):

Gradle plugin version alpha06 seems to have a regression, use alpha05 or later if available.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05' // alpha06 has bug
    ...
}
```